# ASP.Net Web API: Regarding web api action calling url or end point url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i am new in asp.net web api. just reading a article on web api from this url http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/remote-bind-kendo-grid-using-angular-js-and-Asp-Net-web-api/

[image]

### now see this code

```
[RoutePrefix("api/EmployeeList")]  
public class EmployeeDetailsController : ApiController  
{  
    [HttpGet]  
    [Route("List")]  
    public HttpResponseMessage EmployeeList()  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            List<Employee> _emp = new List<Employee>();  
            _emp.Add(new Employee(1, "Bobb", "Ross"));  
            _emp.Add(new Employee(2, "Pradeep", "Raj"));  
            _emp.Add(new Employee(3, "Arun", "Kumar"));  
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _emp, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ex.Message, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);  

        }  


    }  
}
```

as per my understanding the requesting url should be `/api/EmployeeList/List` but if anyone look the above image then must notice different url `api/Employee/GetEmployeeList` is being used to call list action method. so i just like to know the reason why different url is getting issued to call List action function ?

also do not understand how this url `api/Employee/GetEmployeeList` can work in this situation because controller name is `EmployeeDetailsController` but **RoutePrefix** has been used to address it `api/EmployeeList` and action method name is **EmployeeList()** which has been change to List..........so some one tell me how this url `api/Employee/GetEmployeeList` can invoke list action of web api ?

please discuss in detail. thanks

Comment: controller name is EmployeeDetails then how could i point to this controller with keyword like Employee....i have confusion here?

Comment: action name is EmployeeList then how could i access it like GetEmployeeList ?

Comment: Have you configured attribute routing? it maybe not configured and thus convention based routes are used instead, for example if HttpGet is used then Get is prefix to the action name and thus GetEmployeeList. is is recommended that you read more about routing in web api 2, here is a link http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Your code and your POSTMAN response do not match, the user names returned are different. You are forgetting to tell us something. Do your application compile in Visual Studio? Are you calling the correct endpoint? Are you sure you have not another Controller named Employee? Maybe you renamed your controller and didn't recompile.

Comment: if you look at my post then must realize that i said i am learning web api and i also mention url from where i was reading a code for web api sample. i have confusion about endpoint url issued in post man and that is why i asked why the author use different url in postman?

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate [AttributeRouting](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)? If not, standard routing is in place and your current attributes will be ignored.

You need to do this in the WebApi registration process, like this:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Other Web API configuration not shown.
    }
```

Then, you can remove any method call like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
```

to disable conventional routing.

BTW, the call api/Employee/GetEmployeeList is valid because Employee is the name of your controller, Get is the verb and EmployeeList is the name of the method.

Comment: my controller name is `EmployeeDetailsController ` so when i would call this controller then name would be EmployeeDetails......am i right?

Comment: i am not testing the above code rather i was trying to understand why user issue a different url in post man rest client ? see my pic i posted in my question and tell me why user issue a different url in rest client to test the action?

Comment: Yeah, it should be. Probably there is some kind of messy configuration in the route section. Remove all the MapHttpRoute methods and go for the AttributeRouting, it's easier and more clear. It's perfect to avoid this kind of situations :) PS: if you want, you can post your route section too and we can take a look!

Comment: this is the url http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/remote-bind-kendo-grid-using-angular-js-and-Asp-Net-web-api/   from where i got the code. just have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable attribute routing? You do this by default in webapiconfig.cs by adding this line of code:

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

Comment: i am not testing the above code rather i was trying to understand why user issue a different url in post man rest client ? see my pic i posted in my question and tell me why user issue a different url in rest client to test the action?

Answer (score 0):

@Monojit-Sarkar. The URL the user showed in postman did not also match the code. In the code, these are the users we expect to see:

```
        _emp.Add(new Employee(1, "Bobb", "Ross"));  
        _emp.Add(new Employee(2, "Pradeep", "Raj"));  
        _emp.Add(new Employee(3, "Arun", "Kumar"));
```

But the results in postman are different as shown in the image the user posted. So something is disconnected from the article/image and the sample code.